# Financial Metrics Section in Morningstar mutual fund report (blue arrow with white cross?)

Tags: mutual-funds, metric, morningstar-star-rating

Just wondering if anyone out there knows what these blue arrow with white crosses mean under "Financial Metrics". I see them in almost all Morningstar mutual fund reports. Unsure why they would use such an ambiguous graphic. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

([Full page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4hfU.jpg))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you have to upgrade to a Morningstar Premium subscription to actually see the data. The data is currently not available to you unless you subscribe.

I happen to know this because all such purple arrows on Morningstar's website (e.g. on https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/arcx/spy/parent [[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8o9E.jpg)]) lead to a Morningstar Premium [sign up page](https://www.morningstar.com/sign-up/premium) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OExK0.png)) when you click on them.

This is even more obvious when you look at [Morningstar Memberships](https://www.morningstar.com/memberships) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl18i.png)).

The publicly-accessible equivalent of the fund report in your question can be found here: [HSBC US Equity Investor](https://www.morningstar.ca/ca/report/fund/portfolio.aspx?t=0P00007077) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gIUc.jpg)). Notice how the purple arrows are clickable here, unlike those in the report you have.

Comment: oh wow...I thought I was going crazy not understanding the signal, thank you Flux !!

Comment: @ttinggggg You're welcome. Where did you get the screenshot from? Is there a publicly-accessible link to the report?

Comment: here you go: https://awrd.morningstar.com/ectools/hsbc/fund-report/index.aspx?securityId=F0CAN05LVA&languageId=en-CA

Comment: not sure if you can access it directly, if not, use this and pick a random mutual fund performance report: https://www.assetmanagement.hsbc.ca/en/individual-investor/fund-centre#openTab=3&accordion-889559702=8

Comment: Okay, I've found a publicly accessible equivalent: https://www.morningstar.ca/ca/report/fund/portfolio.aspx?t=0P00007077

Comment: that's awesome, wasn't aware of that, now it all makes sense!